# Symfony - Checking isGranted($attribute,$subject) in unit tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am trying to create a unit test in symfony to check if a particular entry in a table which is created by a user 'abc'(stored in column as `createdUserName`) is accessible to other users that try to edit the same entry.

In the controller, using i`sGranted($subject,$attribute)` returns desired result. I am trying to achieve the same in a unit test file and am not sure how to go with it.

I have tried instantiating `AuthorizationChecker` and calling isGranted method, but that threw this error

> 'ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker::__construct()'

Comment: So what arguments did you pass to the `AuthorizationChecker` constructor?

Comment: Did you check the documentation for the AuthorizationChecker to see what parameters are required on its constructor?

Comment: I didnt pass any, assuming it's a code overkill to pass the 3 parameters that are actually required for AuthorizationChecker. Will I have to pass 'TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager, AccessDecisionManagerInterface $accessDecisionManager' from the unit test file?

Comment: I checked the vendor files and found these 3 parameters. I also wanted to know if it is the right way of testing a voter functionality in a unit test.

Comment: $authorizationChecker = new AuthorizationChecker();
        $result = $authorizationChecker->isGranted('edit',$entityobject); This is what I was trying till now